# Why this code is generating duplicate id?

Tags: multithreading, scala

I have the following code to generate unique eventId.  This is not a pure GUID generator but a way to generate unique id across different machines/processes.

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger

object EventIdGenerator extends Serializable {
  val totalBits = 64
  private val epochBits = 42
  private val partitionIdBits = 10
  private val sequenceBits = 12
  private val sequenceInt = new AtomicInteger(0)

  private val maxPartitionId = (Math.pow(2, partitionIdBits) - 1).toInt
  private val maxSequenceId = (Math.pow(2, sequenceBits) - 1).toInt

  def nextEventId(partitionId: Int): Long = {
    assert(partitionId <= maxPartitionId)

    val nextSequence = sequenceInt.incrementAndGet() % maxSequenceId

    val timestamp =  if (nextSequence == 0) {
      Thread.sleep(1)
      System.currentTimeMillis()
    } else System.currentTimeMillis()

    timestamp << (totalBits - epochBits) |
    partitionId << (totalBits - epochBits - partitionIdBits) |
    nextSequence
  }
}
```

This is supposed to be called from a distributed program running over several JVMs in different machines.  Here partition id is going to be unique across different JVMs and machine.

When I run this program in a single thread, it works fine.  But when I run it in multiple threads where each thread calls nextEventId with a unique partition id, sometimes I get duplicate event Ids.  I am not able to figure out what the problem is with the code below.

Answer (score 1):

You have only 1024 different values for `nextSequence`. So if you have request rate more than 1024 per millisecond (for 1 partition) you have ~100% chance of collision. In fact I believe that collision will appear with even much smaller rates because of clock precision.

I see that you tried to sidestep it with `sleep(1)` if you detected an overflow of `nextSequence`. But it doesn't work in a multithreaded environment. A particular partition may even never see `nextSequence` equal to 0.

Comment: Thanks!  The only way I could find to overcome the problem is to synchronized nextSequence and the check to see if nextsequence is 0.

Comment: I think you should search for existing solutions. But if I had to write it myself I'd think about using a combination of a thread id and a thread-local counter. Why using just `UUID.randomUuid` doesn't work for you?